# How to enter a single email address, where there can be more, in the To line of an email?

Tags: vba, ms-access, ms-access-2010

When the user fills out my form I have them select up to 3 email addresses from 3 combo boxes to send the report to. The selected email addresses are put into a string to go into the "To" line of the email.

This is my string:

```vb
[Email1] & ";" & [Email2] & ";" & [Email3]
```

It works great when the user enters 3 email addresses.

If the user selects only 1 email, I get an error. I thought if the user only selects 1 email address it would enter as a blank.

Comment: You need to get rid of the unnecessary `;` when there are no email addresses to separate.

Comment: @SteveLovell if i remove the `;` then Outlook does not recognize the email

Comment: This means could accidentally select same email in multiple comboboxes.

Comment: Outlook generally doesn't mind excess semicolons. This is not reproducible.

Comment: Tested concatenation that would build email string like: `email;;email`. Outlook did not care about the repeated semi-colons nor missing semi-colon at end. Code actually drops one of the `;` because doubling special character escapes it so only one is retained. Also, same email address used twice but only one email sent. I even tested `;email`. Only thing that errors is if no email is provided. As @ErikA said, not reproducible with code provided.

Answer (score 1):

Consider:

`[Email1] + ";" & [Email2] + ";" & [Email3] + ";"`

If field is Null, the + concatenation will return Null and unnecessary `;` will not occur.

Concatenating a string with Null using `&` returns string, whereas concatenating with `+` is like addition with Null, Null is returned.

Probably should also make sure at least one email is provided before sending.

Answer (score 0):

I added `;` to the end of the emails in the table, removed the `;` from my string and this works perfect now.

Comment: Whilst this may "fix" your problem for know, you are almost certainly storing up trouble for the future - for example, any importing/exporting of this data will need to deal with this semi-colon. It would be far better to deal with this properly now.